# CSS for high-resolution images on mobile and retina displays

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, retina-display

My website images look blurry for users with retina displays. (For example, on the Retina MacBook Pro).

How do I serve high-resolution images to visitors with retina displays, but standard-sized images to everyone else, while keeping the image the same apparent size?

Comment: A Javascript solution: [retinajs](http://retinajs.com/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your HTML, create a `<div>` like so:

```
<div class="ninjas-image"></div>
```

And in your CSS, add:

```css
.ninjas-image {
  background-image: url('ninja-devices.png');
  width: 410px;
  height: 450px;
}

@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), (min-resolution: 144dpi) {
  .ninjas-image {
    background-image: url('ninja-devices@2x.png');
    background-size: 410px 450px;
  }
}
```

The magic here is in the CSS `@media` query. We have a double-sized image (ninja-devices@2x.png) that we sub-in when the device reports a ‘device pixel ratio’ of 1.5 (144 dpi) or more. Doing it this way allows you to save on bandwidth by delivering the original, smaller image to non-retina devices, and of course it looks great on retina devices.

**Note:**

This answer was updated in 2016 to reflect best-practice. `min-device-pixel-ratio` did not make it in to the standard. Instead, `min-resolution` was added to the standard, but desktop and mobile Safari don't support it at the time of writing, (thus the `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio` fallback). You can check the latest information at: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-media-resolution.

Comment: You may wish to explain how this code works: what's the purpose of the media query and `background-size` declarations, and so on. (You don't need `-webkit-background-size` anymore, by the way...)

Comment: @BoltClock Have added a little more explanation and removed -webkit-background-size as suggested. Thanks!

Comment: Is it only webkit specific or are there other vedor prefixes? I suspect there is also -moz

Comment: @mastazi Have added in the other vendor prefixes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We've been using the following to handle multiple cases where the ratio is 1.5 or higher - this takes more devices and browsers into account:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
    only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
    only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
    only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
```

We have our entire site Retina enabled: http://www.embraceware.com/

Comment: @ChrisNolet, if you want to revert to the original, you should do a rollback and not try to re-edit.

Comment: Sorry @psubsee2003 - not sure how to do that! I don't see any rollback links on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11063689/revisions. Can you lend a helping hand? Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisNolet my bad... I forgot you don't get the ability to rollback until you have 2K rep.  I will roll it back for you.